# What does "Error: Cycle". means in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

The Terraform docs for some weird reason do not explain what "Error: Cycle" means. I've looked everywhere but there is no mention of it on the official docs. (Turns out it is well-known term, a circular dependency, that someone apparently renamed thinking it would make them sound cool...)

Comment: Sure, someone "renamed" it... in the 18th century. Probably Euler. Cycles on a graph are well established, it's "circular dependency" that's the newcomer.

Comment: Sorry @hobbs, but no, not in the context of software. Euler never wrote a line of code. :)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

As part of Terraform's work, it analyzes the dependencies between your `resource` blocks, `data` blocks, and other configuration constructs in order to determine a suitable order to process them so that the necessary input data will be available.

For example, consider the following contrived simple configuration:

```
resource "null_resource" "foo" {
}

resource "null_resource" "bar" {
  triggers = {
    foo = null_resource.foo.id
  }
}
```

Terraform will analyze the above and notice that the configuration of `null_resource.bar` contains a reference to `null_resource.foo`, and therefore the operations related to `null_resource.foo` must happen before `null_resource.bar`. We can visualize that as a graph where an arrow represents "must happen after", or "depends on":

[image: a box for null_resource.foo and a box for null_resource.bar, with an arrow pointing from the latter to the former]

- Operations for `null_resource.bar` *must happen after* operations for `null_resource.foo`.

---

Consider now what happens if we modify that configuration like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "foo" {
  triggers = {
    bar = null_resource.bar.id
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "bar" {
  triggers = {
    foo = null_resource.foo.id
  }
}
```

Now `null_resource.foo` also refers to `null_resource.bar`. There are now two "must happen after" relationships implied by this configuration:

[image: a box for null_resource.foo and a box for null_resource.bar, with an arrow pointing from the latter to the former, with arrows pointing in both directions between them]

- Operations for `null_resource.bar` *must happen after* operations for `null_resource.foo`.
- Operations for `null_resource.foo` *must happen after* operations for `null_resource.bar`.

The two statements above contradict one another: `null_resource.bar` cannot be processed both before *and* after `null_resource.foo`. Terraform will respond to this situation by reporting a dependency cycle, using the error message you've seen:

```
Cycle: null_resource.foo, null_resource.bar
```

When Terraform returns this error, the solution is to remove at least one of the "must happen after" arrows (dependencies) from the configuration so that it's no longer contradictory. Without seeing your configuration I can't suggest what specific change might achieve that in your case, but it's likely that somewhere in your configuration you have two mutually-dependent resources like this, or perhaps a resource referring to itself.

---

If you are sighted, depending on how complicated your configuration is, it might help to ask Terraform to produce a graph similar to the ones I've included above in this answer, but highlighting the cycles. To do this, you can use [the `terraform graph` command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/graph.html), like this:

```
terraform graph -draw-cycles
```

The output of this command is a description of the graph in the format accepted by [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/). If you don't have Graphviz installed on your local computer, you could instead copy-paste the output into [Graphviz Online](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/) to produce a graph image. The `-draw-cycles` command causes Terraform to mark the arrows that are related to the cycle being reported using the color red. If you cannot visually distinguish red from black, you may wish to first edit the generated Graphviz code to replace `red` with some other color you can distinguish.

The graph visualization of the configuration tends to become unusable for non-trivial configurations because there are so many graphs and edges, so if your configuration has many objects it may be better to follow the dependencies through the configuration itself.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you. I just have to wonder why they used incorrect terminology. This is not a cycle, this is a circular dependency. That would have made it much clearer.

Comment: @JuanJimenez fwiw, I had the exact same thought before I found this answer - why not just call it a circular dependency? Might be worth filing a ticket with Hashi...

Comment: It seems to me that in this contect "dependency cycle" and "circular dependency" are synonyms. For me, the main problem with this error message is that it misses two important parts of a good error message: why does this matter, and what should I do about it? I expect there's probably a way to summarize what I said here into a short paragraph which gives a better clue about what it means and what to do about it. If that includes changing the terminology at the same time then great, but I don't think that's a sufficient change to make this a good error message.

Comment: It's open source. There's no motivation on their part to listen to users on this matter, so they won't do anything, and hence I don't waste my time "file tickets."

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thank you for all the details in your answer. Very helpful.

Comment: Wonderful explaination! THanks

Comment: @Martin Atkins: Thanks for your answer. However: not knowing null_resource, I tried you example, which 'compiles'/'apply's' with terraform v1.2.8. I know it's not your answer, but Hashi does something strange here...

Comment: So TLDR, `Error: Cycle:` means TF has detected a circular dependency in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Next to the excellent explanation above by Martin Atkins, I want to add that in my case the Cycle was not cause by a cycle in the resources, but by a resource which needed to be destroyed.

Terraform could not figure out just to destroy that resource and only look at the new resources.

So, I left with no other option than to Destroy and start over. Which removed the Cycle message.